# Intallation error on Drupal 8.0 RC1

Tags: drupal, vagrant, drupal-8

I tried to install Drupal 8.0.0 RC1 on vagrant with vdd(vagrant drupal development). It shows below error. Anyone knows how to solve it?

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'CLASS' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php on line 226
```

Comment: Is your server running the required minimum version of PHP for Drupal 8? PHP 5.5.9

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to upgrade PHP

`$ php --version`

"Drupal 8 now needs PHP 5.5.9 or higher."
https://www.drupal.org/node/2566085#comment-10314939

Comment: You may try with www.drupalvm.com for installing drupal 8 with simple "vagrant up" - it works very smoothly.